# Open a Specific View controller when user launch UILocalNotification in ViewBased Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am working with UILocalNotification.Here When i Launch the notification i need a specific view in application.But I have tried like below coding .

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:NO];

    SplashView *mySplash = [[SplashView alloc] initWithImage:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash.png"]];

    [window insertSubview:mySplash atIndex:1];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];


    mySplash.delay = 5;
    mySplash.animation = SplashViewAnimationFade;
    [mySplash startSplash];
        [self.window insertSubview:viewController.view atIndex:0];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [mySplash release];

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (localNotification) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Notification Body: %@",localNotification.alertBody);
        NSLog(@"%@", localNotification.userInfo);
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    return YES;

}





- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

showItemContrller = [[Showitem alloc] initWithNibName:@"Showitem" bundle:nil];
        [self.window addSubview:showItemContrller.view];
        [self.window bringSubviewToFront:showItemContrller.view];

}

}
```

But When i launch the notification it is showing the previous view for fraction of seconds the it is going to showItemControllerView.

Thanking you

Comment: Before showing ShowItemController it is showing the Previous state of Application .So how to avoid this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //comment this line.... 

//[self.window insertSubview:viewController.view atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Abishek you  are confusing after receiving LocalNotification it will go to (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification  but it will not enter into DidFinishWithLaunch method.

Comment: see i think you are not getting my point ... just add that default image on default controller... after the splash that controller will show and that controller only has the same default image and after fraction of second you will get your original screen in ..didReceiveLocalNotification: and then don't that line ....

Comment: No Abishek how to add default image on default controller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13038/discussion-between-hariprasad-j-and-abhishek)